# I have a mid 2009 MacBook Pro still on its original software cant upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro

Help me please!!! I have a mid 2009 MacBook Pro running Mac OS X   Version 10.7.5 it won’t let me update it to anything I tried El Capitan  Sierra, high Sierra and nothing I don’t have a disk slot on my computer it was taken off to put another hard drive with a lot of storage and 8gb or ram I tried everything everyone has posted on here! On YouTube. And on other forums can some one please help me 
image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOKN2.jpg)

Comment: In the linked dupe, there are multiple solutions *in addition to* changing the date.